# Create new column with largest number indexes based on values of another column

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame with two columns: 'goods name' and their 'overall sales'. I need to make another column which will contain the indexes with largest sales numerated from 1, 2, 3... Where 1 is the largest number, 2 second largest number and so on.

Hope you can help me.

My dataframe:

```
lst = [['Keyboard1', 1860], ['Keyboard2', 1650], ['Keyboard3', 900], ['Keyboard4', 1230], ['Keyboard5', 1150], ['Keyboard6', 1345],
                   ['Mouse1', 3100], ['Mouse2', 2900], ['Mouse3', 3050], ['Mouse4', 2750], ['Mouse5', 4100], ['Mouse6', 3910]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns = ['Goods', 'Sales'])

       Goods    Sales
0   Keyboard1   1860
1   Keyboard2   1650
2   Keyboard3   900
3   Keyboard4   1230
4   Keyboard5   1150
5   Keyboard6   1345
6   Mouse1  3100
7   Mouse2  2900
8   Mouse3  3050
9   Mouse4  2750
10  Mouse5  4100
11  Mouse6  3910
```

I'm trying to use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df.sort_values('Sales', ascending = False)
df['Largest'] = np.arange(len(df))+1
```

But I get indexes of Largest values for all goods, I need to get Indexes of Largest values for each type of good separately. My result:

```
        Goods  Sales  Largest
10     Mouse5    4100        1
11     Mouse6    3910        2
6      Mouse1    3100        3
8      Mouse3    3050        4
7      Mouse2    2900        5
9      Mouse4    2750        6
1   Keyboard2    1860        7
0   Keyboard1    1650        8
5   Keyboard6    1345        9
3   Keyboard4    1230       10
4   Keyboard5    1150       11
2   Keyboard3     900       12
```

Here is the output I need:

```
        Goods  Sales  Largest
10     Mouse5    4100        1
11     Mouse6    3910        2
6      Mouse1    3100        3
8      Mouse3    3050        4
7      Mouse2    2900        5
9      Mouse4    2750        6
1   Keyboard2    1860        1
0   Keyboard1    1650        2
5   Keyboard6    1345        3
3   Keyboard4    1230        4
4   Keyboard5    1150        5
2   Keyboard3     900        6
```

Comment: You want that the same type of goods be always contiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
# remove any number of groups at the end
df['goods_group'] = df['Goods'].str.replace('\d+$', '')

# sort by the new column and sales
df = df.sort_values(['goods_group', 'Sales'], ascending=False)

# create largest column
df['largest'] = df.groupby('goods_group').cumcount() + 1

# drop the new column
res = df.drop('goods_group', 1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
        Goods  Sales  largest
10     Mouse5   4100        1
11     Mouse6   3910        2
6      Mouse1   3100        3
8      Mouse3   3050        4
7      Mouse2   2900        5
9      Mouse4   2750        6
0   Keyboard1   1860        1
1   Keyboard2   1650        2
5   Keyboard6   1345        3
3   Keyboard4   1230        4
4   Keyboard5   1150        5
2   Keyboard3    900        6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupby`, `Goods` without the digits:

```
>>> df = df.sort_values('Sales', ascending=False)
>>> df
        Goods  Sales
10     Mouse5   4100
11     Mouse6   3910
6      Mouse1   3100
8      Mouse3   3050
7      Mouse2   2900
9      Mouse4   2750
0   Keyboard1   1860
1   Keyboard2   1650
5   Keyboard6   1345
3   Keyboard4   1230
4   Keyboard5   1150
2   Keyboard3    900
>>> df['Largest'] = df.groupby(df['Goods'].replace('\d+', '', regex=True)).cumcount() + 1
>>> df
        Goods  Sales  Largest
10     Mouse5   4100        1
11     Mouse6   3910        2
6      Mouse1   3100        3
8      Mouse3   3050        4
7      Mouse2   2900        5
9      Mouse4   2750        6
0   Keyboard1   1860        1
1   Keyboard2   1650        2
5   Keyboard6   1345        3
3   Keyboard4   1230        4
4   Keyboard5   1150        5
2   Keyboard3    900        6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines to the end of the code:

```
df['new'] = df['Goods'].str[:-1]
df['Largest'] = df.groupby('new').cumcount() + 1
df = df.drop('new', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Goods  Sales       new  Largest
10     Mouse5   4100     Mouse        1
11     Mouse6   3910     Mouse        2
6      Mouse1   3100     Mouse        3
8      Mouse3   3050     Mouse        4
7      Mouse2   2900     Mouse        5
9      Mouse4   2750     Mouse        6
0   Keyboard1   1860  Keyboard        1
1   Keyboard2   1650  Keyboard        2
5   Keyboard6   1345  Keyboard        3
3   Keyboard4   1230  Keyboard        4
4   Keyboard5   1150  Keyboard        5
2   Keyboard3    900  Keyboard        6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It works)